# Include hpp files like dll files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, include

i am trying to include .hpp files (of open_cv if it matters), like a .lib or .dll file. What i mean by that is:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

That is in the top of my .cpp file. Now my thought was if i put opencv2 folder in the debug folder of visual studio it should run like the .lib or .dll files (i have not included anything in properties -> linker like in .lib files - i don;t know if i should), which of course it hasn't done yet. (Of course i know i can include the path but why it is not working?)

Comment: Assuming you mean bin\Debug, that's for binary files, not headers. It wouldn't make sense to include that folder in the default search paths.

Comment: Then let's say that someone want to sell an application or something build in c++. What will he give the client a folder with all the includes and an environmental variable pointing to them?

Comment: The headers ("includes") are only used during compilation.

Comment: All `#include` does is basically copy-paste the file. In the end, you end up with one or more files that embed the included headers, called translation units.